# Group by and order by in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I would like to perform **group by** and **order_by** on model **QFData** 
I am trying the below query however it is not working.

Query 1:

```
data = QFData.objects.filter(Branch_Code__in=branchcode, FldNo__gte=201, FldNo__lte=216) \
             .values('FldNo').aggregate(amt=Sum('Amount')) \
             .order_by('FldNo')
```

However if I want to order_by amt then it might work.
Query 2:

```
data = QFData.objects.filter(Branch_Code__in=branchcode, FldNo__gte=201, FldNo__lte=216) \
             .values('FldNo').aggregate(amt=Sum('Amount')) \
             .order_by(amt)
```

Please help to solve this problem. I would like make Query no. 1 to be working

Comment: when you say it's "not working"...what happens? you get an error?  unexpected result?

Comment: It says : dict object do not have order_by attribute

Answer (score 1):

`aggregate(...)` method returns a dict rather than a queryset, as per the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.aggregate

so the obvious fix is to move your `order_by` call before the `aggregate` call:

```
data = QFData.objects \
           .filter(Branch_Code__in=branchcode, FldNo__gte=201, FldNo__lte=216) \
           .values('FldNo') \
           .order_by('FldNo') \
           .aggregate(amt=Sum('Amount'))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Django [QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/)

> Returns a dictionary of aggregate values (averages, sums, etc)
>   calculated over the QuerySet. Each argument to aggregate() specifies a
>   value that will be included in the dictionary that is returned.

aggregate returns a dictionary according to the documentation and on that you are trying to apply `.order_by` on dictionary.

`order_by` works on querysets. I guess the major problem lies there.

Comment: Agree. but now where to put order_by so that I will get data in this {FldNo,sum(FldVal)} format.

Comment: try putting the order_by before aggregate but that will also lead you to the same set of result when you aggregate because you are summing up the same set of results which are nothing but arranged.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are expecting to get from the query. Have you considered using annotate instead of aggregate? See the django docs on [annotate and values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#values) for more details, but I think you might want to run something along the lines of (untested)-

```
data = QFData.objects.filter(Branch_Code__in=branchcode,
    FldNo__gte=201, FldNo__lte=216) \
    .values('FldNo').annotate(amt=Sum('Amount')) \
    .order_by('FldNo')
```

This should give you a QuerySet instead of a dictionary.

If you are sure you need an aggregate, you can simply sort the dictionary with straight python, using OrderedDict.

See the following sample ([source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes))-

```
# regular unsorted dictionary
d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}

# dictionary sorted by key
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])
```

Which for your case could be (untested):

```
data = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items()))
```